# Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO) SDK getProjectInfo fail when try to create TFS extension

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, vssdk

When implement a TFS extension Widget, our team try to use some VSO API to determine the current version control tool is TFVC or Git. We found there is an API in `VersionCtrlRestClient` can return the project information. But the following code always fail with an 401 NOT AUTHORIZED error.

```
import VersionCtrlRestClient = require("TFS/VersionControl/TfvcRestClient");
versionCtrlClient.getProjectInfo("MyProjectName")
.then(projectInfo => {
    var cont = $("#content");
    cont.append("<pre>" + "TFVC---" + projectInfo.supportsGit + "</pre>");
    cont.append("<pre>" + "GIT ---" + projectInfo.supportsGit + "</pre>");
    cont.append("<pre>" + "GIT ---" + projectInfo.defaultSourceControlType + "</pre>");
});
```

Our extension already register into the following scope, and it is ok to call the API to query code changes from the `versionCtrlClient`.

```
 "scopes": [ "vso.profile", "vso.work", "vso.work_write", "vso.code", "vso.code_write", "vso.code_manage" ]
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to make the API call "AUTHORIZED"?

PS. In the API document of `getProjectInfo`, it is said

```
 * [Obsolete - Use the Projects API instead] Retrieve the version control information for a given Team Project
```

But where can we find the new API to replace it???

Answer (score 0):

The documentation about Project API is here: [CoreHttpClient2_2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/core/restclient/corehttpclient2_2).

To get the version control information, you could use getProject() method with includeCapabilities option. It will returns IPromise that include the version control information.

> capabilities: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: string}}. Set of
>   capabilities this project has (such as process template & version
>   control).